# Javascript automatic form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I took this quick script from another post on StackOverflow, but it doesn't seem to work on my form. It just throws an error saying 'object expected'. Can anyone help me fix it.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onLoad="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form name="EPDQForm" method="post" action="mypage.aspx" >
        <input name="item" type="hidden" value="data">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This is the exact page code (I removed most of it for displaying on here):

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body onLoad="document.forms[0].submit()">

        <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="https://secure2.mde.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdq.e">

            <input name="epdqdata" type="hidden" value="972">
            <input name="returnurl" type="hidden" value="http://www.xxxx.co.uk/Secure/EPDQReturn.aspx">
            <input name="merchantdisplayname" type="hidden" value="xxxxxx">
            <input name="submit" type="hidden" value="purchase">
            <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
            <input name="baddr1" type="hidden" value="152 Smith St">
            <input name="baddr2" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="bcity" type="hidden" value="Manchester">
            <input name="bcountry" type="hidden" value="UK">
            <input name="bpostalcode" type="hidden" value="M4 6DH">
            <input name="email" type="hidden" value="xxxx@xxxx.co.uk">
            <input name="saddr1" type="hidden" value="152 Smith St">
            <input name="scity" type="hidden" value="Manchester">
            <input name="scountyprovince" type="hidden" value="Alderney">
            <input name="scountry" type="hidden" value="UK">
            <input name="spostalcode" type="hidden" value="M4 5GG">

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code shows the error. And I don't see why. In firefox it says:

```
document.forms[0].submit is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is in this part : input name="**submit**" type="hidden" value="purchase".

Submit **input** has the same name as the form function. 
If you replace the name 'submit' by other name (submit1 as example) it should be working as a charm. :-)

Good luck.

Comment: I've updated the question to show my actual full code. This code reproduces the error.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in this part : <input name="**submit**" type="hidden" value="purchase">. Submit input has the same name as the form function. If you replace the name submit by other name (submit1 as example) it should be working as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove the `onload` attribute from your opening `<body>` tag and place this code just before your closing `</body>` tag?

```
<script>
    var frm = document.getElementById('myform');
    if (frm) {
        frm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, the script is executing BEFORE the HTML is fully loaded.

Comment: What if we need to send cookies along the form to make it work?\