# Open Response in browser using .NET

Tags: c#, post, browser, httpwebrequest

How do I make an `HttpWebRequest` (with POST data in it) so that the response (a web page of course) is opened in default browser instead of coming back to me in the code?

The scenario is that I simply want a button in my application clicking which the application will take user to his "home page" (the page that appears AFTER user logs in). The website is simply accepting username and password in two POST fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make response to `HttpWebRequest` to come to browser, plus you will not be able to cheat in necessary cookie on target site.

POST does not have same origin restriction - you can start your own page in a browser and immediately POST correct data to the page in question.

Comment: Can you plz explain your idea in a step-by-step procedure for the people like me? I can't seem to understand how will I submit my dummy page if i open it in a browser.

Comment: @dotNET, search for "javascript automatically submit form" (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634569/javascript-automatic-form-submission)

Comment: Thanks Alexei, let me try that. Just to make sure I'm following it correctly, what you're suggesting is to write this js and fields for my POST variables, save it as a temp file and open it with the browser (using Process.Start), right?

Comment: @dotNET. yes. If you plan to use local file search for "mark of the web" to allow scripts in IE.

Comment: That did the trick, at least in part, so I'll mark it as answer. The only problem I'm facing now is that some of the websites send back cookies which are required to be present in the next request. I can read them in a separate HttpRequest that I make BEFORE opening this temp file in the browser and then use InternetSetCookie API. This technique works fine for IE, but Firefox and Chrome do not get cookie values and thus I get "Enable cookies in your browser" kind of page from the server. Any workaround, just to make your reply a complete solution?

Comment: @dotNET anti-CSRF cookies :)... No I don't know workarounds - you probably want something similar to what you've done for IE as any browser-only approach (code on a page, browser plugin may be an approach) would indicate security issue and likly be fixed quickly.